# How could I draw a lens cross-section with HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'd like to be able to draw the cross section of a lens element. They're generally made up of 1 or 2 circular surfaces (front and back face) and an arbitrarily-shaped rim. For my purposes, I'd just want to draw one or two lines to connect the front and back face.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Each element in this picture is made up of two [probably] circular arcs with between two and six straight lines to connect them. (I'm not worried about drawing aspheric lens elements quite yet).

My initial idea is to draw arcs with the proper arc length, then draw the lines to connect them. My worry with that approach is that the arcs and lines may not match up and there could be either overlap or a gap due to precision errors.

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Can I draw polygons that include both straight and curved edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of drawing pictures of circles, doing some math, and sleeping on it, I came up with the following solution:

```
//draw the top and bottom edges of the lens    
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(lens.x - (lens.thickness / 2), lens.y - lens.radius);
ctx.lineTo(lens.x + (lens.thickness / 2), lens.y - lens.radius);
ctx.moveTo(lens.x - (lens.thickness / 2), lens.y + lens.radius);
ctx.lineTo(lens.x + (lens.thickness / 2), lens.y + lens.radius);
ctx.stroke();


ctx.beginPath();
//draw the left face of the lens
var lensToCircleRatio = lens.radius / lens.leftRadius;
var xOffset = lens.leftRadius * Math.cos(Math.asin(lensToCircleRatio)) - (lens.thickness / 2);  //change the - to a + for a right-side concave face
var arcStart = Math.PI - Math.asin(lensToCircleRatio);
var arcEnd = Math.PI + Math.asin(lensToCircleRatio);
ctx.arc(lens.x + xOffset, lens.y, lens.leftRadius, arcStart, arcEnd);
ctx.stroke();


ctx.beginPath();
//draw the right face of the lens
lensToCircleRatio = lens.radius / lens.rightRadius;
xOffset = lens.rightRadius * Math.cos(Math.asin(lensToCircleRatio)) - (lens.thickness / 2);     //change the - to a + for a left-side concave face
arcStart = -1 * Math.asin(lensToCircleRatio);
arcEnd = Math.asin(lensToCircleRatio);
ctx.arc(lens.x - xOffset, lens.y, lens.rightRadius, arcStart, arcEnd);
ctx.stroke();
```

Here's an image that's really similar to what this code accomplishes:
[image]

It figures out the arc length of each face based on their respective radii of curvature, then figures out where to put the center of these arcs. It then draws the arcs and the edges to connect them if need be. What my code adds to this model is extra lens thickness if both faces of the lens are convex. Luckily, the precision issues that I thought might show up from this approach haven't shown up, even after a number of different sizes and lens configurations.

Here's an early test (drawn with slightly updated code):

[image]